# Importing jar via -classpath switch using a softlink

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I think I'm missing something critical related to classpaths, please point me in the right direction,

The import statement

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
```

The location of the mongodb jar file I'm trying to import. This is a softlink (I can 'cd /baseline/').

```
/baseline/mongodb/lib/mongo-java-driver-2.12.2.jar
```

The location where I'm running my test class

```
/usernameaccount/Desktop/Tester.java
```

The javac command

```
javac -classpath "/baseline/mongodb/lib/mongo-java-driver-2.12.2.jar" Tester.java
```

The error I get says this

```
Tester.java:11: error: package baseline.mongodb.lib does not exist
import baseline.mongodb.lib.Mongo;
```

What am I missing? Thanks for your patience

Comment: Well, does you `mongo-java-drive-2.12.2.jar` contains a package `baseline.mongodb.lib`? Unjar it and check it out.

Comment: no, baseline/mongodb/lib/ is the filepath to the jar...and I fixed the import statement after examining the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the file structure (and thus altering the filepath) I was able to get it to compile and run. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two thing. 
The import statement should include the class location and classpath should point to the location of jar.

change

```
import baseline.mongodb.lib.Mongo;
```

to

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
```

and re-run the program.

Comment: edited the java class, recompiled and got this error (package com.mongodb.Mongo does not exist)